# Unable to upload SQL database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms-2016, sql-server-2016-express

Im using SQL server 2016 and SSMS to manage database, im trying to deploy my database to azure through the deploy wizard and end with failure. Pls find below steps:

1. Right click database, select "Deploy database to azure VM"
2. Sign in with azure account.
3. Fill cloud name and virtual machine name, the thing to note here is storage account drop down is greyed out with name as dbdeploywizard. There is no way i can change this.
4. Go to settings and select image type, setup username and password.
5. The setup failed with the error message given below -

> Oct 15 2016 12:51:45 Task:e823a582-8d5c-4d00-80f1- 
>   4858c2652cd3:Validation: Running: 0%: Failed:  ConflictError 
>   The storage account named 'dbdeploywizard' is already taken. Oct 15
>   2016 12:51:45 [Error]
>   Task:e823a582-8d5c-4d00-80f1-4858c2652cd3:Validation: Running: 0%:
>   Failed: Validation Started. Retry = 2.

The above message loops upto 10 times.

Im not sure what's that im doing wrong here, pls help.